# I'm looking to extract the text before an UNDERSCORE("_") in a string of text using WIndows Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a batch script which does the following.

1. We get files with naming convention similar to `2604230_VIJAY_TAX_02-NOV-2018.xls in C:\temp\`
2. I want to extract the strings before the Underscore(`_`) from the filename and save it to variables
3. For example from `2604230_VIJAY_TAX_02-NOV-2018.xls` filename, I want to extract `2604230`, `VIJAY`, `TAX` and `02-NOV-2018` and save them to variables.

Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: Type `for /?` for help. Use the underscore as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is in fact off topic, but I will show you one way at least on how to echo each token, regardless.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_" %%i in ('dir /B /A-D "c:\temp\*_*.xls"') do echo %%i %%j %%k %%l
```

This simply splits the string by the `_` and assigns 4 tokens to each value split.

If you want to actually assign them to vaiables, you would need to use the set command, if inside a loop, you would probably need `delayed expansion` so I suggest you open `cmd.exe` and run the following commands to get the help files

```
for /?
set /?
setlocal /?
```